How can I append comma except lastline?
With following shell script,

I read file
and for each line
generates SQL fragments

#!/bin/bash
CURRDATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
echo $CURRDATE
echo $OUTPUT

echo "SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT = 0;" > $OUTPUT
echo 'START TRANSACTION;' >> $OUTPUT

echo $'INSERT INTO ...' >> $OUTPUT
echo 'VALUES' >> $OUTPUT
cat $INPUT | tr -d '\r' | while IFS= read -r LINE; do
echo $"(..., '$LINE', ...)," >> $OUTPUT
done

echo "COMMIT;" >> $OUTPUT


The output look like this,
SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET @created_at = '2024-08-09 09:30:45';
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES
(...),
(...),
(...), -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< should be a semi-colon
COMMIT;

How can suppress the last comma? So that I put semi-colon?

What database engine are you using? What is the format of the input file? If it's CSV, can't you just import the data straight into the table instead of creating SQL to do it?  This would also deal with the issues you would otherwise have if any field contains single quotes.

I'm also noticing that your scrip definitely does not produce the output that you say it does. Ut would be good if you could ensure that the provided code corresponds with the given output.

It's a comma because your outputline
echo $"(..., '$LINE', ...)," >> $OUTPUT
makes it a comma.

@Wastrel I know, right?

@JinKwon I don't know much about SQL, but I guess you want only the last line of output to have a semicolon instead of a comma, not all of them. That was my misunderstanding. I wouldn't input the file with cat and read in the first place. I'd make an array, from which I could find the last line and treat it differently. As others suggest, a shell script might not be the best tool for this, but it can be done.

If the data is in a TSV file, you should be able to load it with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE tablename.  If it's CSV, you also has to specify the field delimiter and quoting character etc., but it's literally a few extra words. There is no need to do individual INSERT statements, and it much faster.

I believe this will do what you want:
CURRDATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
echo $CURRDATE
echo $OUTPUT

echo "SET SESSION AUTOCOMMIT = 0;" > $OUTPUT
echo 'START TRANSACTION;' >> $OUTPUT

echo $'INSERT INTO ...' >> $OUTPUT
echo -n 'VALUES' >> $OUTPUT
comma=
cat $INPUT | tr -d '\r' | while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    echo $comma                    >> $OUTPUT
    echo -n $"(..., '$LINE', ...)" >> $OUTPUT
    comma=,
done
echo ';' >> $OUTPUT

echo "COMMIT;" >> $OUTPUT

The -n for the echo says don't include a newline after the output.

Note that $'...' is quite different from $"..." in the bash shell. In this code, neither of these types of strings seems to be useful.

Also, this would replace any embedded whitespace with single spaces, would perform filename globbing with any data that looks like a globbing pattern, and would break if the data contains single quotes.

@Kusalananda, yeah, I was a bit pained by the $" and $'.  I tried to keep the original syntax since the OP was not asking about quotes.  I know $'...\n' can give you the actual new line, etc as requested but I've never been clear on $"...".  It seems like that is for international character sets or something but I never spent the time to find out.

This is something that's pretty simple to do with awk once you wend your way to the how of it.  I use this to "sqlify" any list of items into an SQL-friendly list.  You can adapt the BEGIN and END sections to add the extra statements and other preamble that you need before (and after) your list of values:
BEGIN {
  printf "( "
}

NF > 0 {
  gsub( /'/, "''", $0 )
  printf( "%s'%s'", comma, $0 )
}

NR==1 {
  comma=","
}

END {
  printf( " )\n" )
}

Example usage:
$ seq 3 | awk -f sqlify.awk
( '1','2','3' )

The logic is:

Print whatever we need before the comma-separated list, and set the "comma placeholder" to an empty string.
For each value:
Print the comma-placeholder, followed by the "SQLified" value
If this is the first value we just printed, set the comma-placeholer to a ,
Done with the list of values? Cool, print whatever we need after the list.

The upshot of this is, because we're printing the commas on the lines following each value, no comma is printed for the last value.
In my example, I take in a list of values and output a quoted, comma-separated list.  If you don't need to add quotes, alter the printf line accordingly.  (The gsub line will correctly escape any strong quotes in your values so that the SQL will do what is intended/expected)

An unintentional quirk since I just copied the script I use day-in and day-out and I know I am providing one item per line (with no whitespace) to myself.  This is a good catch though for general distribution.

Perl equivalent for DopeGhoti's sqlifier:
perl -l -0777 -F'\n' -e "
    print('( ' .
        join(
            ', ',
            map {
                q(') . s/'/''/gr . q(')
            } @F)
    . ' )')
"

One-liner version:
perl -l -0777 -F'\n' -e "print('( ' . join(', ', map { q(') . s/'/''/gr . q(') } @F) . ' )')"


-l: autochomp / autoappend the input record separator (\n)
-0777: read the whole file / STDIN at once
-F'\n': set the input field separator to a newline character and autosplit the whole file / STDIN on the input field separator; turn autolooping on
-e "[...]": for each field, replace single quotes with double single quotes, wrapping the resulting string in single quotes; join all fields using ,  as a separator and print the resulting string, wrapped in parenthesis

Note: In older versions of Perl, you may need to add the -a and -n switches (to turn on autosplitting and autolooping); in Perl 5.20.0 or newer, both are implied by -F.
% printf "Foo\nBar\nString with spaces and 'single quotes'\n" | perl -l -0777 -F'\n' -e "print('( ' . join(', ', map { q(') . s/'/''/gr . q(') } @F) . ' )')"
( 'Foo', 'Bar', 'String with spaces and ''single quotes''' )


sed
sed 's/\r$//; $!s/$/,/' "$INPUT"


s/\r$// removes the carriage return from the end of line
$!s/$/,/ on the last line ($) NOT (!), replace end of line with a comma.

